# "Iterable<Element> cannot be cast to List<Element>" - Isn't `List` a type of `Iterable`?

Tags: java, list, classcastexception, iterable

I called a `getElements` method which returns `Iterable<Element>`.

I did this:

```
List<Element> elements = (List<Element>) getElements();
```

This generates the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.utesy.Element$3 
cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

**I thought a `List` was a type of `Iterable`?**

Comment: post the code of `getElements();` method

Comment: The `List` interface extends the `Iterable` interface - so yes, `List` is of type `Iterable`, as you say. But that doesn't mean that whatever `Iterable` is returned by `getElements` is also a `List`. All Lists are Iterables, but not all Iterables are Lists.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, `List<T>` extends `Iterable<T>`, but that doesn't mean that you can cast from *any* `Iterable<T>` to `List<T>` - only when the value *actually* refers to an instance of a type of `List<T>`. It's entirely possible to implement `Iterable<T>` without implementing the rest of the `List<T>` interface... in that case, what would you expect to happen?

To put it in simpler terms, let's change `Iterable<T>` to `Object` and `List<T>` to `String`. `String` extends `Object`, so you can *try* to cast from `Object` to `String`... but the cast will only succeed at execution time if the reference *actually* refers to a `String` (or is null).

Answer (score 28):

You can turn Iterable into a List with

```
List<Element> elements = Lists.newArrayList( getElements() );
```

Comment: This is the most concise way to do it. Otherwise you'll need a long implementation :-( -- or just use Scala ;)

Answer (score 18):

`List<Element>` is a type of `Iterable<Element>`, but that doesn't mean that all `Iterable<Element>` objects are `List<Element>` objects.  You can cast a `List<Element>` as an `Iterable<Element>`, but not the other way around.

An apple is a type of fruit, but that doesn't mean that all fruits are apples.  You can cast an apple as a fruit, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 5):

why not:

```
    Iterable<Element> i = ...; //is what you have
    List<Element> myList = new LinkedList<Element>();
    for (Element e:i) {
        myList.add(e);
    }
```

?
needs no google lib.

Answer (score 2):

List extends Collection which in turn extends Iterable. You therefore trying to cast to a subtype which won't work unless getElements() really is returning a List (which the signature doesn't in any way guarantee).

See: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Answer (score 1):

`List` is a *subinterface* of `Iterable` meaning that List includes pretty much everything that Iterable has, however not the other way around. So not all methods in a List instance would have an equivalent in Iterable.

Try to avoid that sort of casting.

I would recommend you to take a quick look at the [Java 6 API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and the tutorials covering casting

Answer (score 0):

Not all `Iterable`s are `List`s, thus it's not safe to cast an arbitrary `Iterable` to a `List`.

**Take any `Set` for instance**, a `HashSet` is `Iterable` but the elements has no order, so it can't implement the `List` interface, and is thus not a `List`.

Comment: `<nit-pick>` "but the elements has no order, so it's not a `List`" - that's not the reason that a `HashSet` isn't a `List`. A `HashSet` isn't a `List` because it doesn't implement the `List` interface. `</nit-pick>`

Comment: @Matt Ball, true... reformulated a bit... better? :)

Answer (score 0):

From exception message it is clear that 
`Iterable<Element>` **is not castable to** `List<Element>`

SO you need to return `List<Element>` from `getElements()`

Answer (score 0):

List implements the Iterable interface but this doesn't mean Iterable can be cast back to List. Iterable is much more general and may be Hash or some exotic type that bears no relation to List. (It looks like getElements() returns an instance of some anonymous inner class contained alongside getElements within its class).

If getElements would happen to contain Lists then this would be a valid cast. As the type returned by getElements() wasn't actually a List this produces a run-time error.

Comment: List implements Iterable, and this *does* mean that it can be cast to it.  The problem the OP is having is going the other way.  This has nothing to do with it being an implement vs extend.

Comment: Sorry, the "doesn't mean it can be cast it" was unclear, I've filled in the "it"s so it can't be wrongly interpreted as you have.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to place a guard with `instanceof`:

```
if (AnElement instanceof AList){
    //cast
    AList = (AnList)Element
}
```