# Returning an Iterable collection

Tags: java, arraylist, iterable

The goal is to return an iterable collection values from an inorder tree traversal. My inorder traversal method adds all of the necessary Positions into an ArrayList (named 'positions'), and I then loop through this list of positions, accessing the values within that position object and adding them to a second ArrayList (named 'returned') which is returned.

I checked the java docs and ArrayList implements Iterable, so returning it should be no problem. I'm getting an error stating that the two are not compatible. Below is the code in question:

```
/** Returns an iterable collection of the keys of all entries stored in the 
*  map (in inorder). */
  public Iterable<K> keySet() {
        ArrayList<Position<Entry<K,V>>> positions = new ArrayList<Position<Entry<K,V>>>();
        ArrayList<K> returned = new ArrayList<K>();
        if(!isEmpty())
            inorder(root(), positions);
        for(int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++){
            Position<Entry<K,V>> pos = positions.get(i);
            K key = pos.element().getKey();
            returned.add(key);
        }
        return returned;
  }
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

```
error: incompatible types: ArrayList<K> cannot be converted to Iterable<K>
        return returned;
               ^
```

Comment: Mysterious, because this very basic case works: Iterable<K> test() { return new ArrayList<>(); }  Just to make sure - are you importing java.lang.Iterable and java.util.ArrayList?

Comment: Possible duplicate see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959892/iterableelement-cannot-be-cast-to-listelement-isnt-list-a-type-of-it

Comment: @chut, I'm importing both. This has me completely stumped

Comment: does your code compile if you reduce it down to the simplest test case? E.g. create a new list and return it?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question mentioned above by  user35736644892, that question is about the opposite cast. There must be a problem elsewhere in your code, it really should work. Try reducing to a minimalistic version, as in chut's answer, and working from there.

Comment: Seconding @chut, I suggest to check all your imports for stray foreign imports of some Iterable or ArrayList.

Comment: Compiled on another machine and works fine. Thanks for the help all